# Is there any provision in VS 2008 to enter symbol file path as WinDbg?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there any provision in VS 2008 to enter symbol file path as WinDbg? Because the project which i want to debug contains lots and lots of dlls and that too the hierarchy of the dll folders is very deep. Its a difficult task to create hierarchy of the directories every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i have come to know that i can provide the symbol files path same like WinDBG in Visual studio.

Please follow the below steps:

Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols

This option is there from VS 2005 onwards (not sure about previous versions of Visual studio).